# My code returns me single value instead of a vector

Tags: r

This is the code. I am trying to find out the sum of geometric series. It should return 4 values for 4 values of n but returns only a single value with a warning message.

```
n <- c(10,20,30,40)
j <- 1:n
r <- 1.06
A <- r^j
A
sum(A)
```

> Warning message:
>   In 1:n : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used`

Comment: I want to calculate sum of A for n=10,20,30,40. Where j should go 1 to 10 ,1 to 20,1to 30,1 to 40 .  Sum for these 4 cases.

Comment: Is this what you need? `sapply(n, function(x) sum(1.06**(1:x)))`?

Comment: @NelsonGon Can you explain the code little . I got the answer yes. But I just started learning R.

Comment: It's just the same thing as you did but in a more R-like fashion(Vectorization?). By stating `1:n`, you're only using the first value of `n` but `*apply` allows you to loop over those values.

Comment: @NelsonGon I don't know about it sorry. I am familiar with sequence and repetation commands right now.

Comment: Little by little, was there too. Still learn something everyday.

Comment: @markus  can you please help me with basic syntax both of your syntax are using function and I am not yet taught function in my college class.

Comment: @NelsonGon an you please help me with basic syntax both of your syntax are using function and I am not yet taught function in my college class

Comment: @markus Why did we use function(x)

Comment: @markus Can you do some modification here ? 
`r=1.06
A <- function(n)(sum(r^(1:n)))
A((c(10,20,30,40)))
compare_with <- function(n) (r - r^(n + 1))/(1 - r)
compare_with(c(10,20,30,40)) `

Comment: @markus It returns 4 values for `compare_with` but not with `A`

Comment: @markus That gave me answer yes but I am trying to avoid this sapply command.

Comment: It would be more straightforward to do `cumsum(r^(1:max(n)))[n]`

Comment: @AndrewGustar can you explain me use of max(n) and [n] here

Comment: @AndrewGustar Wow thanks I understood thanks. You should put it as answer I ll tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more straightforward approach would be just to sum the series once using `cumsum`, and take the values indicated by the vector `n`.  So with `r` and `n` defined as above...

```
cumsum(r^(1:max(n)))[n]    #i.e. sum 40 values and take 10th, 20th, 30th and 40th of them

[1]  13.97164  38.99273  83.80168 164.04768
```